# ICommand Command not working in Maui Preview 11

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm new to using Maui and was following a Xamarin forms tutorial to design a login page. I can't seem to get past the login page as the binding for button is not firing. 
I'm getting this in the output window but can't find any fix for this anywhere. 
The application seems to run fine, just the two buttons which do not respond to user interaction.

```
[ViewRootImpl@ae55060[MainActivity]] MSG_RESIZED: frame=[0,0][800,1280] ci=[0,32][0,0] vi=[0,32][0,426] or=1
[0:] Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element: Warning: Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout is already a child of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout. Remove Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout from Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout before adding to Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout.
[0:] Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element: Warning: Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout is already a child of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout. Remove Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout from Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout before adding to Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout.
[0:] Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element: Warning: Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout is already a child of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout. Remove Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout from Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout before adding to Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout.
[0:] Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element: Warning: Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout is already a child of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout. Remove Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout from Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout before adding to Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout.
[0:] Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element: Warning: Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Border is already a child of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout. Remove Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Border from Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout before adding to Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout.
[0:] Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element: Warning: Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label is already a child of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout. Remove Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label from Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout before adding to Microsoft.Maui.Controls.GridLayout.
```

#### Login.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
<StackLayout> Image and Label over here </StackLayout>
<StackLayout Margin="10" Padding="20" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

            <Border Stroke="#620774"
                    StrokeThickness="4"
                    Padding="16,8"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!--Email Address-->
                    <Image 
                        GridLayout.Column="0"
                        GridLayout.Row="0"
                        Source="email.png"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           WidthRequest="20"
                           HeightRequest="35"/>

                    <Entry
                        GridLayout.Column="1"
                        GridLayout.Row="0"
                        PlaceholderColor="#9d2888"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Placeholder="Email Address"
                        Keyboard="Email"/>

                    

                    <!--Password-->
                    <Image Source="key.png"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                        GridLayout.Column="0"
                           GridLayout.Row="1"
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           WidthRequest="20"
                           HeightRequest="35"/>

                    <Entry
                        GridLayout.Column="1"
                        GridLayout.Row="1"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        PlaceholderColor="#9d2888"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Placeholder="Password"
                        IsPassword="True"/>

                </Grid>
            </Border> 
    
            <Label Text="Forgot Password?"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   Margin="0,15,0,15"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   TextColor="#0052FF">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ForgotPassword}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>

</StackLayout>
<StackLayout>
            <Button Text="LOGIN"
                    MaximumHeightRequest="45"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    TextColor="White"
                    Margin="2"
                    BackgroundColor="#620774"
                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>


            <Button Text="Dont have an account? Register here!"
                    MaximumHeightRequest="45"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    TextColor="White"
                    BackgroundColor="#620774"
                    Margin="2"
                    Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}"/>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout> 2 Labels here </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

#### Login.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
        }
    }
```

#### LoginViewModel.cs

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        //private fields
        private string _username;
        private string _password;

        public string Username
        {
            get { return _username; }
            set { _username = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set { _password = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        //Commands
        public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand RegisterCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ForgotPassword { get; set; }

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("INSIDE LOGIN VIEWMODEL");
            LoginCommand = new Command(UserLogin);
            RegisterCommand = new Command(NewUser);
            ForgotPassword = new Command(ResetPassword);
        }
        public async void UserLogin()
        {
        }
   }
```

Comment: Maybe start with the simplest test you can? A single stacklayout with a button, and debug writeline in the command method?

Comment: That's a good technique @ToolmakerSteve, I'll use this whenever I get stuck the next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work, by making 2 changes. However, these changes affect the vertical spacing of the page. See if this works for you, then try to find a different way to get the desired layout.

1. Remove `VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"` from `StackLayout`.
2. Remove `VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"` from `Label`.

Login.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTests.Login"
             Title="Login"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="LOGIN"
                    MaximumHeightRequest="45"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    TextColor="White"
                    Margin="2"
                    BackgroundColor="#620774"
                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>

        <!-- VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" -->
        <StackLayout Margin="10" Padding="20">

            <Border Stroke="#620774"
                    StrokeThickness="4"
                    Padding="16,8"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!--Email Address-->

                    <Entry
                        GridLayout.Column="1"
                        GridLayout.Row="0"
                        PlaceholderColor="#9d2888"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Placeholder="Email Address"
                        Keyboard="Email"/>



                    <!--Password-->
                    <Entry
                        GridLayout.Column="1"
                        GridLayout.Row="1"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        PlaceholderColor="#9d2888"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Placeholder="Password"
                        IsPassword="True"/>

                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <!-- VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" -->
            <Label Text="Forgot Password?"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   Margin="0,15,0,15"
                   
                   TextColor="#0052FF">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ForgotPassword}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>

        </StackLayout>


        <Button Text="Dont have an account? Register here!"
                    MaximumHeightRequest="45"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    TextColor="White"
                    BackgroundColor="#620774"
                    Margin="2"
                    Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it still wasn't working after trying this but your solution gave me a sense of what might be the problem. So I removed all the vertical options from root layouts and  the buttons started working! I'm guessing it has something to do with overlapping of the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with the community toolkit and the RealyCommand (See Videos YouTube comments for RelayCommand rather than ICommand).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Qga2pniN78

I just could not get ICommand to work properly for some reason and I have my button inside a .NET MAUI Carousel view.

I also needed to use the full path address in the XAML (as per the video):
e.g. `<Button Text="Submit" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:MonitoringSubmissionViewModel}}, Path=ShowMessageCommand}" />`

to reach my relay command code method in my partial MVVM class:

```
public partial class MonitoringSubmissionViewModel : ObservableCollection<CheckListDataBoundItem>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        
              [RelayCommand]
              private void ShowMessage()
              {
                  // Add the action you want to perform when the button is clicked
                  //App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Button Clicked", "Hello from ICommand!", "OK");
                  Console.WriteLine($"Button clicked.");
              }
        
        
              private ObservableCollection<MonitoringSubmission> monitoringSubmissions;
    
    // More class stuff in here
}
```